# How do you display date in this format? "Jul 18, 2018 at 10:02 AM"

Tags: swift, date, dateformatter

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "UTC")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2018-07-18T17:02:02.614Z")
```

date description prints: 2015-06-18 17:02:02 +0000
Playground seems to naturally outputs this on the right side: "Jun 18, 2015 at 10:02 AM"

How do I format it to display this? "Jul 18, 2018 at 10:02 AM"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to format `date` (which is now a `Date` instance) using another `DateFormatter`. And you should use date and time styles, not a fixed format for this.

And "UTC" is not a locale, it's a timezone. But you don't need that. But you should use the special locale of `en_US_POSIX` when parsing a fixed format date string.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2018-07-18T17:02:02.614Z")
if let date = date {
    let outputFormatter = DateFormatter()
    outputFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
    outputFormatter.timeStyle = .short
    let output = outputFormatter.string(from: date)
    print(output)
}
```

Output:

> Jul 18, 2018 at 11:02 AM

Note that the time will depend on your local timezone. By default the output will be in local time so don't expect the output to be `17:02` since that is the time in the UTC timezone.

Comment: Thank you, it works!    I was setting the style in the dateFormatter, no wonder it was doing nothing.

Comment: Why not **if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2018-07-18T17:02:02.614Z")**

Comment: @Sh_Khan That works too. I just added the `if let` onto the existing code. And sometimes intermediate variables help with debugging.